# Handle click in parent and child in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, native

I have a from where a user can enter data:

```
<View>

 <TextInput
  clearable
  value={textInput1}
  onChangeText={setTextInput1}
 />

 <DropDownPicker
  open={isDropdownOpen}
  value={value}
  items={items}
  setOpen={setIsDropdownOpen}
  setValue={setValue}
  setItems={setItems}
  />

</View>
```

I want now, that when the Dropdown (react-native-dropdown-picker) is open and where ever a user touches / presses, the dropdown should close. The dropdown should be closed, when the user touches the textinput or the heading or the background. When the user selects an item of the dropdown, it should be selected.

So i thought i capture the event in the parent, before the bubbling starts by adding this to the parent:

```
 onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={isDropdownOpen}
 onPress={() => setIsDropdownOpen(false)}
```

But now all events are captured, also the clicks on the dropdown, so selecting an item is not possible. So i was trying to:

1. check for the event target, to only handle the click in the parent, when the click is not fired from the dropdown, by doing something like this

```
onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={event.target != dropdown && isDropdownOpen}
```

But i could not get this working, not sure how a correct comparison by event.target with a component could work.

2. Capture the event and then continue bubbling, i want to do the opposite of `stopPropagation()`, but could not find anything like this.

How can I handle all outside clicks and close the dropdown and handle clicks inside the dropdown correctly?